# Alternative for MS Research Chess?

Tags: .net, multithreading, unit-testing

Is there any alternative for MS Research CHESS library for unit testing .net multithreading applications?

Comment: What are the deficiencies in CHESS that an alternative wouldn't have?

Comment: CHESS project is closed and support for Visual studio 2010 is never released.

Comment: So, you are looking for an **open source** alternative that has **VS 2010 support**?

Comment: No, I am looking for the best alternative... Doesn't matter open source it or not...

Comment: This questions deserves some good answers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about unit testing, but I've found [Jinx](http://corensic.com) useful ( commercial product with trial )

Comment: Oh! Thank you a lot! It would be very nice to collect all the list of available now tools and libraries. Does anybody know about any else things?